# On which platforms/compilers sizeof(short) is NOT 2?

Tags: compiler-construction, types, sizeof, platform

Tried to look for that and didn't find an answer.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: It's worth to note that in C `short` type must have at least 16 bits. I'm also interested where it has more bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are DSPs that don't allow for integers of less than 32 bits. See [this](http://focus.tij.co.jp/jp/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?literatureNumber=spra757&fileType=pdf) for instance.